# rsync deletes SO slow - any ideas?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

I have several instances running on Amazon EC2 (in the same availability zones).

I'm running this command from the master to update all the slaves:

```
rsync -avz -e '$ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $keyfile' --delete --exclude 'logs/*' $dir_sync ec2-user@$server:$dir_sync
```

**Everything works fine, except - deletes are *so slow*.**

It's taking at least 2 minutes per 400-600mb file.

Shouldn't it just blitz it?

Any clue?

**Update:**

Actually, I logged into the slave instance and tried `rm file`, and it took the same length of time, so I'm guessing this isn't an rsync issue, but a filesystem one.

The question becomes... how the heck do I quickly zap a file?

It's running on a Large EC2 instance and the files are only 400mb... should they really take 40-120 seconds to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Lee,

This can happen due to several reasons:

- A disk problem. I doubt if this is the case, since you're in the EC2
- Hard disk parameters configured wrongly. Very rare, but still a possibility
- General high I/O activity that slows things down. If the server is under a lot of work load, this might effect every action, including file deletion
- Other applications are using the files, thus taking it longer to delete

The 2nd item seems to me like a direction in which you should direct your efforts. It's either a bad choice of filesystem, or someone might have tried to tweak the HD parameters, and jumbled things up.

Good luck!
Dotan